# Poincare Section of a system of second order odes

Tags: python, numpy, ode, nonlinear-functions

It is the first time I am trying to write a Poincare section code at Python.

I borrowed the piece of code from here:

https://github.com/williamgilpin/rk4/blob/master/rk4_demo.py

and I have tried to run it for my system of second order coupled odes. The problem is that I do not see what I was expecting to. Actually, I need the Poincare section when `x=0 and px>0`.

I  believe that my implementation is not the best out there. I would like to:

- Improve the way that the initial conditions are chosen.
- Apply the correct conditions (`x=0 and px>0`) in order to acquire the correct Poincare section.
- Create one plot with all the collected poincare section data, not four separate ones.

I would appreciate any help.

This is the code:

```
from matplotlib.pyplot import *
from scipy import *
from numpy import *

# a simple Runge-Kutta integrator for multiple dependent variables and one independent variable

def rungekutta4(yprime, time, y0):
    # yprime is a list of functions, y0 is a list of initial values of y
    # time is a list of t-values at which solutions are computed
    #
    # Dependency: numpy

    N = len(time)

    y = array([thing*ones(N) for thing in y0]).T

    for ii in xrange(N-1):
        dt = time[ii+1] - time[ii]
        k1 = dt*yprime(y[ii], time[ii])
        k2 = dt*yprime(y[ii] + 0.5*k1, time[ii] + 0.5*dt)
        k3 = dt*yprime(y[ii] + 0.5*k2, time[ii] + 0.5*dt)
        k4 = dt*yprime(y[ii] + k3, time[ii+1])
        y[ii+1] = y[ii] + (k1 + 2.0*(k2 + k3) + k4)/6.0

    return y

# Miscellaneous functions
n= 1.0/3.0
kappa1 = 0.1
kappa2 = 0.1
kappa3 = 0.1
def total_energy(valpair):
    (x, y, px, py) = tuple(valpair)
    return .5*(px**2 + py**2) + (1.0/(1.0*(n+1)))*(kappa1*np.absolute(x)**(n+1)+kappa2*np.absolute(y-x)**(n+1)+kappa3*np.absolute(y)**(n+1))

def pqdot(valpair, tval):
    # input: [x, y, px, py], t
    # takes a pair of x and y values and returns \dot{p} according to the Hamiltonian
    (x, y, px, py) = tuple(valpair)
    return np.array([px, py, -kappa1*np.sign(x)*np.absolute(x)**n+kappa2*np.sign(y-x)*np.absolute(y-x)**n, kappa2*np.sign(y-x)*np.absolute(y-x)**n-kappa3*np.sign(y)*np.absolute(y)**n]).T

def findcrossings(data, data1):
    # returns indices in 1D data set where the data crossed zero. Useful for generating Poincare map at 0
    prb = list()
    for ii in xrange(len(data)-1):
        if (((data[ii] > 0) and (data[ii+1] < 0)) or ((data[ii] < 0) and (data[ii+1] > 0))) and data1[ii] > 0:
            prb.append(ii)
    return array(prb)

t = linspace(0, 1000.0, 100000)
print ("step size is " + str(t[1]-t[0]))

# Representative initial conditions for E=1
E = 1
x0=0
y0=0
init_cons = [[x0, y0, np.sqrt(2*E-(1.0*i/10.0)*(1.0*i/10.0)-2.0/(n+1)*(kappa1*np.absolute(x0)**(n+1)+kappa2*np.absolute(y0-x0)**(n+1)+kappa3*np.absolute(y0)**(n+1))), 1.0*i/10.0] for i in range(-10,11)]

outs = list()
for con in init_cons:
    outs.append( rungekutta4(pqdot, t, con) )


# plot the results
fig1 = figure(1)
for ii in xrange(4):
    subplot(2, 2, ii+1)
    plot(outs[ii][:,1],outs[ii][:,3])
    ylabel("py")
    xlabel("y")
    title("Full trajectory projected onto the plane")

fig1.suptitle('Full trajectories E = 1', fontsize=10)


# Plot Poincare sections at x=0 and px>0
fig2 = figure(2)
for ii in xrange(4):
    subplot(2, 2, ii+1)
    xcrossings = findcrossings(outs[ii][:,0], outs[ii][:,3])
    yints = [.5*(outs[ii][cross, 1] + outs[ii][cross+1, 1]) for cross in xcrossings]
    pyints = [.5*(outs[ii][cross, 3] + outs[ii][cross+1, 3]) for cross in xcrossings]
    plot(yints, pyints,'.')
    ylabel("py")
    xlabel("y")
    title("Poincare section x = 0")

fig2.suptitle('Poincare Sections E = 1', fontsize=10)

show()
```

Comment: Create the `y` array in the rk4 procedure more directly as `y=zeros((len(time),)+y0.shape)`.

Comment: Why do you try to implement and use a Runge–Kutta method yourself? There are several existing modules for this which are more sophisticated than what you do.

Comment: Thanks you for your comments!  @Wrzlprmft I tried to use `odeint` but I could not figure out how to use the data afterwards. Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: @Mitscaype: It’s hard to answer this without seeing what you tried. Please ask a separate question.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Thanks for coming back. You are right, I will first try to figure out the answer from this thread, then I will jump on to another question. If you have any suggestions for this piece of code, I would appreciate it, or even a suggestion on where to look for a similar topic that I could taylor to my problem. Again, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to compute the derivatives of the Hamiltonian correctly. The derivative of `|y-x|^n` for `x` is

`n*(x-y)*|x-y|^(n-2)=n*sign(x-y)*|x-y|^(n-1)`

and the derivative for `y` is almost, but not exactly (as in your code), the same,

`n*(y-x)*|x-y|^(n-2)=n*sign(y-x)*|x-y|^(n-1)`,

note the sign difference. With this correction you can take larger time steps, with correct linear interpolation probably even larger ones, to obtain the images

[image: phase plot]
[image: cross section]

I changed the integration of the ODE to

```
t = linspace(0, 1000.0, 2000+1)
...
E_kin = E-total_energy([x0,y0,0,0])
init_cons = [[x0, y0, (2*E_kin-py**2)**0.5, py] for py in np.linspace(-10,10,8)]

outs = [ odeint(pqdot, con, t, atol=1e-9, rtol=1e-8) ) for con in init_cons[:8] ]
```

Obviously the number and parametrization of initial conditions may change.

The computation and display of the zero-crossings was changed to

```
def refine_crossing(a,b):
    tf = -a[0]/a[2]
    while abs(b[0])>1e-6:
        b = odeint(pqdot, a, [0,tf], atol=1e-8, rtol=1e-6)[-1];
        # Newton step using that b[0]=x(tf) and b[2]=x'(tf)
        tf -= b[0]/b[2]
    return [ b[1], b[3] ]

# Plot Poincare sections at x=0 and px>0
fig2 = figure(2)
for ii in xrange(8):
    #subplot(4, 2, ii+1)
    xcrossings = findcrossings(outs[ii][:,0], outs[ii][:,3])
    ycrossings = [ refine_crossing(outs[ii][cross], outs[ii][cross+1]) for cross in xcrossings]
    yints, pyints = array(ycrossings).T
    plot(yints, pyints,'.')
    ylabel("py")
    xlabel("y")
    title("Poincare section x = 0")
```

[image: cross-sections overlaid]
and evaluating the result of a longer integration interval
[image: with longer integration]

Comment: Hi and thanks for taking the time to answer. I went over the calculations once again and I located the mistake, thank you. Could you please help me optimize the code (maybe RK4 is not the best way to integrate here) and also, how to acquire just one plot for the phase space and one poincare section for all the initial conditions? These four plots correspond to only four ICs is that right? Thank you again.

Comment: Yes, this is for the first 4 IC, as taken from your code. I do not see how that could be a good idea to put all those plots into one, even differentiating by color. Or are you thinking about making an animation of it? You could easily replace your RK4 routine with `scipy.integrate.odeint`, using sparse `t` sampling. Then find the zero crossings via Newton's method using short integrations

Comment: Not an animation but all the Poincare sections, after time `t`, differentiated by color. It would give a general idea of what the structure looks like. If it is not too much, could you provide the modified code, so that I can run it? If not, could you direct me to some source where I could study and write something that works? Much appreciated.

Comment: Thank you! Can I ask, is my way of applying the conditions x=0 and px>0 correct in that piece of code I have provided? I see that you kept it the way it was therefore I guess it was ok, or is it?

Comment: Yes, as long as the sampling density is high enough that you get at least one point per traversed quadrant. Which you get with a step size smaller than 1, I think.

Comment: Alright, I will go through this tonight and let you know about any questions I might have. Thank you!

Comment: Ok, I think I got it. Everything is clear, thank you for helping me out with this one.

Comment: Sorry for coming back, but I have the following question: How would you modify the `refine_crossing` if you had 3 degrees of freedom, say `x,y,z, px, py,pz` and you wanted to plot the section of `y,py`against for example `x,px`? I tried something but I am not quite sure if it is correct.

Comment: A small correction to my comment above, I meant the section against `x, px` and `z,pz`. Thank you again.

Comment: You are computing the intersection of a curve with a hyperplane. To show something you need to project this codimension 1 hyperplane to 2 dimensions. If there is no obvious projection, you could use principal component analysis to find the more interesting directions.

Comment: I see. Let me know if I am thinking this in the correct way. I am fixing the initial `px` in terms of energy `E` as before and then I take `x0=y0=z0=pz=0` while varying `py`. Then I have modified the `findcrossings` condition as: `if ((((data[ii] > 0) and (data[ii+1] < 0)) or ((data[ii] < 0) and (data[ii+1] > 0))) and data1[ii] > 0) and ((((data2[ii] > 0) and (data2[ii+1] < 0)) or ((data2[ii] < 0) and (data2[ii+1] > 0))) and data3[ii] > 0)`. Now, I am not sure how to write down the `refine_crossing`. I really appreciate any help.

Comment: You have the wrong idea of a Poincaré section. You have some quasi-periodic solution that stays relatively close to some closed center curve. Then you take a plane perpendicular to that center curve and look at the trace of that solution on that one plane.

Comment: But that is what I mean with the above comment. I numerically solve the system for a variety of initial conditions. I know I will get back some periodic and some quasi-periodic curves, depending on the ICs. Then, the dim(6) phase space drops to a dim(5) due to energy conservation. Now, to get back a section `y, py` should I refine my numerical results by "cutting" through the space `x=0 and px>0 and z=0 and pz>0`? Would this collection resemble a "section" in this 4 dimensional space? The problem is, I am no sure at all how to translate this in a code.