# How to implement a method to generate Poincaré sections for a non-linear system of ODEs?

Tags: numpy, scipy, ode, numerical-integration

I have been trying to work out how to calculate Poincaré sections for a system of non-linear ODEs, using a paper on the exact system as reference, and have been wrestling with `numpy` to try and make it run better. This is intended to run within a bounded domain.

Currently, I have the following code

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint
X = 0
Y = 1
Z = 2

def generate_poincare_map(function, initial, plane, iterations, delta):
    intersections = []
    p_i = odeint(function, initial.flatten(), [0, delta])[-1]
    for i in range(1, iterations):
        p_f = odeint(function, p_i, [i * delta, (i+1) * delta])[-1]
        if (p_f[Z] > plane) and (p_i[Z] < plane):
            intersections.append(p_i[:2])
        if (p_f[Z] > plane) and (p_i[Z] < plane):
            intersections.append(p_i[:2])
        p_i = p_f
    return np.stack(intersections)
```

This is pretty wasteful due to the integration solely between successive time steps, and seems to produce incorrect results. The original reference includes sections along the lines of 
[image: Reference solution]

whereas mine tend to result in something along the lines of 
[image]

Do you have any advice on how to proceed to make this more correct, and perhaps a little faster?

Comment: Can you give your dynamical system or confirm that the Mathematica example of the Arnold-Beltrami-Childress (ABC) flow `x'[t] = 3/4 Cos(y[t]) + Sin(z[t]), y'[t] = Cos(z[t]) + Sin(x[t]), z'[t] = Cos(x[t]) + 3/4 Sin(y[t])` is a suitable test example? https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/new-in-9/advanced-hybrid-and-differential-algebraic-equations/poincare-sections.html

Comment: I've been working with the ABC flow, so it would be a great example.

Comment: I just answered a more specifically asked question about computing the ABC Poincaré cross section in [scicomp: Poincare map for Arnold-Beltrami-Childress Magnetic Field in Python](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/q/29823/6839)

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48892663/poincare-section-of-a-system-of-second-order-odes for a 4D Hamiltonian flow on a 3D hypersurface of constant energy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a Pointcaré map of the ABC flow

```
def ABC_ode(u,t):
    A, B, C = 0.75, 1, 1 # matlab parameters
    x, y, z = u
    return np.array([
        A*np.sin(z)+C*np.cos(y), 
        B*np.sin(x)+A*np.cos(z), 
        C*np.sin(y)+B*np.cos(x)
    ])

def mysolver(u0, tspan): return odeint(ABC_ode, u0, tspan, atol=1e-10, rtol=1e-11)
```

you have first to understand that the dynamical system is really about the points `(cos(x),sin(x))` etc. on the unit circle. So values different by multiples of `2*pi` represent the same point. In the computation of the section one has to reflect this, either by computing it on the Cartesian product of the 3 circles. Let's stay with the second variant, and chose `[-pi,pi]` as the fundamental period to have the zero location well in the center. Keep in mind that jumps larger `pi` are from the angle reduction, not from a real crossing of that interval.

```
def find_crosssections(x0,y0):
    u0 = [x0,y0,0]
    px = []
    py = []
        
    u = mysolver(u0, np.arange(0, 4000, 0.5)); u0 = u[-1]
    u = np.mod(u+pi,2*pi)-pi
    x,y,z = u.T

    for k in range(len(z)-1): 
        if z[k]<=0 and z[k+1]>=0 and z[k+1]-z[k]<pi:
            # find a more exact intersection location by linear interpolation
            s = -z[k]/(z[k+1]-z[k])  # 0 = z[k] + s*(z[k+1]-z[k])
            rx, ry = (1-s)*x[k]+s*x[k+1], (1-s)*y[k]+s*y[k+1]
            px.append(rx); 
            py.append(ry);
    return px,py
```

To get a full picture of the Poincare cross-section and avoid duplicate work, use a grid of squares and mark if one of the intersections already fell in it. Only start new iterations from the centers of free squares.

```
N=20
grid = np.zeros([N,N], dtype=int)
for i in range(N):
    for j in range(N):
        if grid[i,j]>0: continue;
        x0, y0 = (2*i+1)*pi/N-pi, (2*j+1)*pi/N-pi 
        px, py = find_crosssections(x0,y0)
        for rx,ry in zip(px,py):
            m, n = int((rx+pi)*N/(2*pi)), int((ry+pi)*N/(2*pi))
            grid[m,n]=1
        
    plt.plot(px, py, '.', ms=2)
```

[image]

You can now play with the density of the grid and the length of the integration interval to get the plot a little more filled out, but all characteristic features are already here. But I'd recommend re-programming this in a compiled language, as the computation will take some time.

Comment: Thank you very much! Out of interest, is there any reason you decide to calculate the section for the interval `-pi, pi`, or is it arbitrary?

Comment: I wanted to have `0` well in the middle of the interval so that the intersections are well away from the jumps produced by the reduction to a single period. So `[-pi,pi]` seemed the most natural for an interval of length `2*pi`.